# Find jsonb array length in stored procedure postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have maked a jsonb array(jsonb[]) by pushing jsonb object using array_append function in stored procedure. But after that,  I can't find the length of that jsonb[]. I have tried with jsonb_array_length(jsonb[]). But its showing error like "ERROR:  function jsonb_array_length(jsonb[]) does not exist". Can somebody help?

my jsonb array (flexibleWorkouts) is something like {"{\"workoutId\": 1, \"workoutType\": \"Flexibility\", \"workoutCategory\": \"Activity\"}"}

My code is

```
jsonb_array_length(flexibleWorkouts)
```

Comment: `jsonb[]` is an array of json (similar to `text[]`), not a "JSON array". You need to use `cardinality()` to get the length of a native array.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot. It is working now. Is it possible to find an object from this same array using index value ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried with flexibleWorkouts[0] and flexibleWorkouts:: json-> 0. But not working. Have any idea for that ?